# Android Radio Buttons if or switch?

Tags: android, radio-button, switch-statement, onclicklistener, buttonclick

[image]

Hey everyone, I am in need of some help with my first android app, and I have a little experience in programming. So first I wanted to do was something like "Let the user choose whichever method they want to convert from and to, and let them input the value in the TextView then follow by pressing the convert button to finish it with a toast."

Currently I am having trouble with `onClickListener()` button to finish of with a toast output, I can't get the result from the String in switch/case. Also I am not sure that if my code is okay, as I cannot test it :(. I Spent hours trying to get it work but no luck. Need someone to point me to the right direction and what I need to look at, please.

```
    class convert_handler_CMtoM implements Button.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btnDisplay) {

            if (MMtoCM.isChecked())
            {
                int Amount = (int) Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
                int formula = (int) (Amount * 10) ; 
                String result = String.valueOf(formula);
            }

            if (CMtoMM.isChecked())
            {
                double Amount = (double)Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
                double formula = (double) (Amount / 10) ; 
                String result = String.valueOf(formula);
            }
        }

    }   

    private OnClickListener btnDisplay = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
            Toast.makeText(second.this, rb.getText(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package com.example.radiobuttongroup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.radiobuttongroup.R.id;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RadioButton rd1, rd2, rd3;
    Button btn1;
    int type;
    String title;
    EditText input;
    AlertDialog.Builder editalert;
    AlertDialog alertd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rd1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id.radioButton1);
        rd2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id.radioButton2);
        rd3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id.radioButton3);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(id.button1);



        rd1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rd2.setChecked(false);
                rd3.setChecked(false);
                type = 1;
                title = "cm to m";
            }
        });

        rd2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rd1.setChecked(false);
                rd3.setChecked(false);
                type = 2;
                title = "m to cm";

            }
        });

        rd3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rd2.setChecked(false);
                rd1.setChecked(false);
                type = 3;
                title = "mm to cm";
            }
        });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculate(title, type);

            }
        });
    }

    void calculate(String title, final int type) {
        try {

            editalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertd = editalert.create();
            editalert.setTitle("Calculator");
            editalert.setMessage(title);
            input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            input.setText("1000");
            editalert.setView(input);

            editalert.setPositiveButton("Convert",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            int value = Integer.valueOf(input.getText().toString());

                            switch (type) {
                            case 1:
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        MainActivity.this,
                                        String.valueOf(value / 100),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                                alertd.dismiss();
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        String.valueOf(value * 100),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                                alertd.dismiss();
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        String.valueOf(value / 100),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                                alertd.dismiss();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    });
            editalert.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("hata", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I have to create an inner class? and where do I put the "private OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on clicks
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
        Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};" ?

Comment: wow...you have just made it look so simple... hats off to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) and set a [RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html).

Use a global `int` and set it to the `checkedId` parameter of the listener each time the user changes the selection of the `RadioButton`.

When the 'Convert' button is clicked, simply use the id of the `RadioButton` last selected in a `switch` block to decide which conversion to use.